# Why don’t animal cells fall apart when they are out of water?

Tags: cell-biology, cell-membrane

Cell membranes are formed because of the phospholipid's shape and properties. The hydrophilic heads will arrange themselves to surround the hydrophobic tails, so the hydrophilic heads always face the water while hydrophobic tails are shielded. But out of water, there is only water on the inside, and not outside, so shouldn’t the cell membrane just fall apart when the cell is out of water?

Comment: But do animals really dry out without dying? I mean...early land animals like amphibians die if their skin dries out and more developed land animals have mechanisms to protect from drying out while the insides of animals are universally wet.

Comment: Why would a cell membrane fall apart when out of water? interaction forces between neighboring phospholipids don't disappear.